# equal datagrid with textbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

i want search in cell[1] when text = with text box show me id .

i have a equal text in `DataGrid` but always show me

```
not matching...
```

i use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagrid_customer.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text) == txtcom.Text)
    {
        txt_f1.Text = Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
    }
    else
    { txt_f1.Text = "Not Matching..."; }
}
```

what problem

what should i do?

`DataGrid` code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_customer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="322" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Margin="668,105,-667,0"  Width="699" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          SelectionChanged="datagrid_customer_SelectionChanged"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="کد محصول" Binding="{Binding MahID}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام محصول" Binding="{Binding MahName}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="B Yekan" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. You're trying to update the same `txt_f1.Text` on every iteration of the `for` loop. What's actually need to be achieved?

Comment: i want  when textbox.text = datagrid then show id the item

Comment: You should work with the data that's bound to the datagrid rather than extract data back out the UI. But also. Have you got anything selected?

Comment: Oh. Also. Do not repeat code. ( DRY ).  If you're doing some manipulation gives a string and then use it twice, use a variable so you do the manipulation once.